# Loop through multiple folders to perform a command then write to file in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a number of directories containing zips. I am trying to loop through each directory extracting the zips and placings them in a separate directory. In my script it is going into the first directory and performing the command but it is getting stuck and not moving to the next.

```
for f in ./*; do 
    i=0
    [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && for archive in somelog.log.*; do
        ((i++))
        unzip -p $archive > ../extracted/extractedlog_$i.log
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to undo the `cd`. Add `cd -` or `cd "$OLDPWD"` at the end of the outer loop.